# Is a Field Norm a Norm?

Tags: normed-spaces, extension-field

The norm $N(a)$ of an $a$ element of a field extension $K/L$ is the determinant of the matrix representing multiplication by $a$. It has the following properties:
$$
N(a b) = N(a)N(b) \\
N(ka)=k^n N(a)
$$
where $ a,b\in L$ and $k\in K$ and $n$ is the degree of the extension.

But there is no mention of addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the field norm is not a norm in the sense of normed vector spaces.

One reason is that the field norm takes values in $L$ and vector space norms take values in $\mathbb R$.

Even when $L \subset \mathbb R$, the field norm is not a vector space norm because it can be negative.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm#Example) offers this example: In $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, the field norm of  $ 1+\sqrt{2}$ is $-1$.

Comment: Indeed, two parts of the definition of a vector space norm wouldn't even make sense unless the field is ordered: $\|x\| \geq 0$ and $\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$.

Comment: if we take a ordered field L  only when norm of field is works as norm on vector space . Am I correct sir ?